# Delete pending invoice on Dynamics AX

Tags: windows, dynamics-ax

When I right click on a pending invoice, I don't see an option to delete it in the context menu:

[image]

So how do I delete a pending invoice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to open the invoice by double clicking it, and then in the dialog itself there is a delete button:

[image]

Click that button to delete the pending invoice.